# passing large amount of html throught $ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am making a product add page for e commerce and after the data is being submitted then a ajax call pass all the data to the query page and it stores the info to the database. but the problem is when a large amount of html data is being passed then it dosent pass anything in the `description` . suppose write a short paragraph in description area then it pass throught ajax easily . but whenever there is long paragraphs or lets a very large amount of html data. it fails . the code i am using is

```
function product()
{
var micategory=$('.micatg option:selected').val();
var misubcategory=$('.misubcatg option:selected').val();
var currency=$('.micurrency option:selected').val();
var looking_for=$('input:radio[name=lookingfor]:checked').val();
var title=$('.btitle').val();
var condition=$('input:radio[name=bcondition]:checked').val();
var buy_description=CKEDITOR.instances['textarea_description_add'].getData();

var buy_country=$('.bcountry option:selected').text();
var buy_city=$('.bcity').val();
var zipcode=$(".bzipcode").val();
var price=$(".bprice").val();
var video_link=$("#infolink").val();
var address=$(".baddress").val();
var loguser=$("#loginuser").val();
var product_id=$("#prod_id").val();
var dataString = 'category='+ micategory+'&subcategory='+misubcategory+'&currency='+currency+'&looking_for='+looking_for+'&title='+title+'&condition='+condition+'&country='+buy_country+'&city='+buy_city+'&zipcode='+zipcode+'&price='+price+'&video_link='+video_link+'&address='+address+'&loguser='+loguser+'&product_id='+product_id+'&description='+encodeURIComponent(buy_description);
alert(dataString);

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "modules/buy&sell/add_prod.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
alert(html);
alert("Your Product is Successfully Added");
window.location = "buy.php";
 }
 });
}
```

in this due to large amount of html i used `encodeURIComponent` reading somewhere in stack. but still no help with this. can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ***`POST` instead of `GET`***, Because of size limitation of `GET`.

within ajax config object.

So, it will look like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "modules/buy&sell/add_prod.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'html', // add this if you only passed html, if have other value then remove it
    success: function(html) {
        alert(html);
        alert("Your Product is Successfully Added");
        window.location = "buy.php";
    }
});
```

Comment: but apart from that description i am passing several other values too . so would it be good using dataType:'html' ?

Comment: then is there a need to use `encodeURIComponent(buy_description)` ?

Comment: @ParamVeer No need.. and if you passed other values the don't use `dataType:html`

Comment: kk u said to remove `encodeURIComponent(buy_description)` thats why it didnt worked . i used it again with post . now its working thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think this is due to the limit on the data size when passing data with the GET method.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request).

You should use the POST method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use post method ,

type: "Post",

With Get method we can send limited data. It depends on browser.